# Add a `v-text-field header` to `v-data-table` header for column based search

Tags: vue.js, header, vuetify.js, v-data-table

#### Target:

I am planing to add custom search to my `v-data-table` which filters on a per column basis. For example if I have the table

```
ID | Name | Age
```

I'd like to add a `v-text-field` to the `Name`and `Age` header to enable custom filtering on those two columns.

#### Current Setup:

This can easily be achieved by adding a template to the `v-data-table` like such

```
<template v-slot:header.name="{ header }">
    <v-text-field
        :label="header.text"
    >
    </v-text-field>
</template>
```

### The Problem:

This solution does work but it doesn't look pretty at all
*this is what it looks like in [codepen](https://codepen.io/SquirrelInTraining/pen/oNLyzoy?editable=true&editors=101%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fvuetifyjs.com%2Fen%2Fcomponents%2Fdata-tables%2F)* [image]
As one can clearly see, the font is bigger than for the default headers and the "sort arrow" has moved down a line.

Now I'm looking for a solution how to make the custom `v-text-field` header look like the other default headers.
My assumption is that I'd have to use css for styling but I am unsure.
Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated! ☺

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This terrible css will work:

```
thead.v-data-table-header > tr > th > div{
  display:inline-block;
  width:90%;
}

thead.v-data-table-header > tr > th > div.v-input label{
  font-size:12px
}
```

[Example codepen](https://codepen.io/DAustin985/pen/LYZrRag)